# "Maximum" vs. "maximal"

Tags: word-choice, differences, adjectives

What is the difference in usage between **maximum** and **maximal**? When would you use one or the other?

*Maximum* can be a noun or an adjective:

> This is *the maximum* it can be set to.
>     This is *the maximum value*.

whereas "maximal" is always an adjective:

> This is *the maximal value*.

Is this correct? Is there more to it than that? When would you use one or the other as an adjective, or are they completely interchangeable?

Comment: In your third example, _maximum_ must be a typo for _maximal_.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

There is a subtle difference; *maximum* and *minimum* relate to absolute values — there is nothing higher than the *maximum* and nothing lower than the *minimum*. *Maximal* and *minimal*, however, can be more vague.

In "I want to buy this at minimal cost" and "this action carries a minimal risk", *minimal* means "very small" as opposed to "the lowest possible"; the same distinction is true of *maximum* and *maximal*.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  Seems like a reasonable answer.

Comment: I don't believe this answer is correct. The usage you cite is simply a misunderstanding about 'maximum' etc., which are frequently used to mean 'very big' rather than their correct meaning which is 'the biggest'.

Comment: Surely if words are frequently used to mean something then that becomes their correct meaning? Language isn't static. After all the question was about difference "in usage" not "in original meaning"

Comment: Really? I’m with Clay and Waggers.

I’ve been listening to English for only 60 years and I’ve yet to notice ‘maximum’ ever used to mean 'very big' rather than 'the biggest’

If I had from more than about age 12, I’d have been sure that in the unlikely event the speaker knew the difference, he surely didn’t care.

‘Maximum’ is the greatest; ‘maximal’ is tending towards the greatest.

People who neither know nor care are welcome to make up their own language and to try to explain their own rules but please don’t let’s kow-tow to that…

Comment: @ DJClayworth Once it's listed without caveat in a respectable dictionary, the people saying that the usage is wrong also need to check their facts. 'Minimal' (covered in your 'etc' here) is certainly used acceptably for 'very low / negligible'.

Comment: Though I can easily find the looser definition for 'minimal' (negligible ...) that is commonly used, I can't find a corresponding  looser definition for 'maximal'. English is idiosyncratic; arguing from analogy isn't reliable. You need to post an authoritative supporting reference.

Answer (score 46):

Waggers' answer does an excellent job of explaining the difference in the non-technical meaning. In some areas of mathematics (e.g., in maximal element, maximal matching), a *maximal* value (you can't use *the* with this meaning) is essentially a local maximum—it's a maximum value in its neighborhood; i.e., there are no small changes which will increase the value. See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_element) for a more technical description in relation to partially ordered sets.

Comment: It seems to me that mathematical definition (*a maximal value=the local maximum*) effectively means the same as @Waggers "non-technical" one anyway. A maximal value would not be so called if it was easy to identify a higher one "nearby" (whatever "nearby" meant in context).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: you're right ... it's essentially a mathematical adaptation of the non-technical definition.

Comment: I have seen maximal used like in Peter's answer: In my algorithms class we used maximal to mean that we would have to backtrack to get a better(larger) answer.

Comment: In [this two peaks graph](https://www.google.com/search?q=x^3%2Bx^2%2Bx%2B1&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#safe=off&q=-%28x^4-8x^2%2B3x), is the *maximal* point the lower peak? I know that in math, the point near zero is call *minimum*, but it seems that it doesn't suit the normal meaning.

Comment: Both the higher and lower peaks are maximal; only the higher one is maximum.

Answer (score 18):

The short answer is that, unless you are a mathematician or an economist, there is no difference. However, there is a distinction between the two terms in the context of partially ordered sets (i.e. sets in which not every pair of elements need be comparable).

An element is *maximal* if there is no other element greater.

An element is *maximum* if it is itself greater than every other element.

If the "elements" under discussion are numbers, the definitions coincide, but there are contexts in which the distinction matters.

For example, in an election one might say that candidate 1 is *strictly better* than candidate 2 if all potential voters prefer candidate 1 to candidate 2. Say that three candidates - Mitt, Barry, and Adolf - are running for president of a club.

The club members are divided into two contingents of equal size. One group unanimously prefers Barry to Mitt and Mitt to Adolf, while the other unanimously prefers Mitt to Barry and Barry to Adolf.

Barry and Mitt are both strictly better candidates than Adolf, as all members rank Adolf last. But since some members prefer Barry to Mitt and some prefer Mitt to Barry, neither is strictly better than the other. Thus neither can be maximum with respect to this ordering. However, because no candidates exist that are strictly better than either of them, both candidates *are* maximal with respect to this ordering.

Mathematicians make another distinction between the terms when considering sets that satisfy a certain property.  For example, a "clique" is a set of people all of whom know each other.  A clique is *maximal* if adding anyone else to the set destroys the clique property, that is, there is no larger clique that contains it.  A clique is *maximum* if there is no larger clique.  For example, if Alice, Bob, and Cam know each other, and Deb, Ed, Fran, and Gay know each other, but
none of the first three know any of the other four, then Alice,Bob,Cam are a maximal clique but not a maximum clique.   There can be many maximum cliques. 
Every maximum clique is maximal, but not vice-versa. The other answer about backtracking is another example of this distinction because backtracking in a search means removing an element from a set.